# Reuse Angular Application in Container Application

Tags: angular, web-applications, components, micro-frontend, angular-elements

I have a more fundamental question in regards of Angular Applications. I built an small Application using Angular and Spring Boot. The application is a small reservation app where the user can add, delete and see all existing reservation on an dashboard.

Now i would like to use this reservation app additionally within another web app, which should be the container of several small web application.

Can anyone give me a some hints how this can be achieved (if at all)?

During my research I read about Web Components and Micro Frontends but not sure if i understand the concept:

My open questions there are the following:

- Can i just pack my whole Angular app as Web Component (e.g Angular Elements) and integrate them  in my container app?
- Isn't my current Angular app not already something like an Micro-Frontend which i can add to my container app?
- What is the best approach if i need to run the container app for different Environments (Can i somehow environize the integrated apps)?
- What is the best approach for Versioning the integrated apps?